# Is there any gyroscope, accelerometer & magnetometer sensor built in for modern Macs?

Tags: macos, mac, hardware

**Is there any gyroscope, accelerometer & magnetometer sensor built in for modern Macs?**

We know all modern smartphones contain these sensors. I wonder if modern Macs contains any such sensors built-in into them or not.

Answer (score 3):

**iMacs** don't have any those.

**MacBooks** have accelerometer called SMS - Sudden Motion Sensor to protect hard drives when MacBook gets dropped. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudden_Motion_Sensor

**iPhones/iPads** have all of those.

Custom sensors (old information): https://logi.wiki/index.php/SMC_Sensor_Codes

Comment: Is there any public API you know of for getting data from SMS?

Comment: It's possible to get information: http://matth.github.io/UnimotionPlugin/ However, i'm not sure this is considered public, you need to try it in sandboxed environment.

Comment: Do modern MacBooks still have the SMS sensor, considering they don't have mechanical harddrives anymore?

Comment: Good question. They have it, but don't use it. At least for Intel-based ones. Can't find any information about Apple's silicon-based (since late 2020) https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201666